# count number of patterns

Tags: bash, shell, csv, count, pattern-matching

I have a `CSV` file, and I wanna remove the columns that have less than 5 different values. e.g

```
a b c;
1 1 1;
1 2 2;
1 3 4;
2 4 5;
1 6 7;
```

then I wanna remove column `a` since it has only two different values (1,2). How to do this?

Comment: Sounds suspiciously like some homework assignment...  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution using arrays:

```
infile="infile.txt"

different=5
rows=0

while  read -a line ; do
  data+=( ${line[@]/;/} )                        # remove all semicolons
  ((rows++))
done < "$infile"

cols=$(( ${#data[@]}/rows ))                     # calculate number of rows

result=()
for (( CNTR1=0; CNTR1<cols; CNTR1+=1 )); do
  cnt=()
  save=( ${data[CNTR1]} )                        # add column header
  for (( CNTR2=cols; CNTR2<${#data[@]}; CNTR2+=cols )); do
    cnt[${data[CNTR1+CNTR2]}]=1
    save+=( ${data[CNTR1+CNTR2]} )               # add column data
  done
  if [ ${#cnt[@]} -eq $different ] ; then        # choose column?
    result+=( ${save[@]} )                       # add column to the result
  fi
done

cols=$((${#result[@]}/rows))                     # recalculate number of columns

for (( CNTR1=0; CNTR1<rows; CNTR1+=1 )); do
  for (( CNTR2=0; CNTR2<${#result[@]}; CNTR2+=rows )); do
    printf " %s" "${result[CNTR1+CNTR2]}"
  done
  printf ";\n"
done
```

The output:

```
 b c;
 1 1;
 2 2;
 3 4;
 4 5;
 6 7;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think to resolve this problem you can read this file to get data (numbers) (can put in a array) then search columns you want to remove and write this result back to file at last.